# How to log to a Text file an input form and activate function using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fwrite

I want to log a user input form into a text file on server, 
As well onclick button triggers a function gives a status result from another server, which works well. how can I let a button trigger 2 functions right. If I use submit type button the return function doesn't work.
how do I fix these to work together on one click?

html:

```
<form action="" method="POST"><input class="input" type="text" name="search" id="search" value="" size="13" height="20" width="150" maxlength="13" id="ItemCodeNoPopup" dir="ltr" autocomplete="on">
<input type="button" value="חפש" name="button" align="absmiddle" border="0" alt="submit" onclick="showDiv(); logger();"></form>
```

post.js:

```
document.getElementById('quickContactForm')
$(document).ready(function(){
//$("#hiddenDiv").hide();
});

function showDiv(){
  var str=$("#search").val();
  var url="action.php?show="+str;
  console.log('url'+url);
  $.get(url,function(data,status){
  //   alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
      $("#hiddenDiv").html(data);
      $("#hiddenDiv").show();
  });

    function logger(){
       var str=$("#search").val();
       currentTime = new Date().getTime();
       console.log(currentTime);
       data = [currentTime,str];
       $.post('logger.php',function(data){
       });
    }
```

action.php works well.

logger.php

```
<?php
 $Date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
 var str=$("#search").val();
 var ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
 $file = fopen("log.txt","a+");
  fwrite($file,$str,$ip);
  fwrite($file,$Date. "\n");
  fclose($file); 
  print_r(error_get_last());
}
?>
```

Comment: Can't you just call the js logger function from the `showDiv()` function?

Comment: I've eventually use only showDiv() and call to logger.php from Action.php. worked! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If logger.php doesn't depend on result of action.php I suggest to call logger.php in action.php. So you don't need to make two http reqeusts to server. Only one is necessary.

Action.php:

```
require_once('logger.php')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a callback to the second function if the first function is successful.

```
document.getElementById('quickContactForm')
$(document).ready(function(){
 //$("#hiddenDiv").hide();
});

    function showDiv(){
     var str=$("#search").val();
  var url="action.php?show="+str;
  console.log('url'+url);
  $.get(url,function(data,status){
  //   alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
      $("#hiddenDiv").html(data);
      $("#hiddenDiv").show();
       //callback to logger once the first function is completed
       logger();
  });

function logger(){
   var str=$("#search").val();
   currentTime = new Date().getTime();
   console.log(currentTime);
   data = [currentTime,str];
   $.post('logger.php',function(data){
   });
}
```

You can remove logger from onclick to check